# .bashrcファイル削除後、その結果をすぐ反映させるには？

Tags: bash, unix

**ユーザホームディレクトリへ配置していた.bashrcファイルを削除しました**
・この時、結果をすぐ反映させるにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？
※新しくログインしたら反映されるのですが、そうすることなくすぐに反映させる方法はあるでしょうか？

**試したこと**

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

・「.bashrc」を削除したため、「そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません」と表示されました

```
 $ source .bash_profile
```

・上位階層ファイルを再読込すれば反映されるかな、と思ったのですが効果ありませんでした

Comment: `.bash_profile` ファイルの中であらゆる設定をリセットあるいは上書きしているなら `source .bash_profile` で済むでしょうが、そうなってないなら期待通りにはならないですよね。例えば `.bash_profile` で環境変数 `$FOO` を設定する記述があって、`.bashrc` に環境変数 `$BAR` を設定する記述があったらどうなるか考えればわかるかと。なので、すでに回答にあるように bash を起動しなおす (`-l` オプションはログインシェルとして起動することを意味する) のが簡単・確実です。

Comment: 「例えば」の説明を読んで「なるほど」と思いました。-l オプションの説明も参考になりました

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`exec` でシェルを起動すると、.bashrc などの削除・変更を反映することができます。(現在起動中のシェルが置換されます。)

```
exec $SHELL -l
```

Comment: 期待通り動作しました。参考になりました

Comment: 元のシェルを使っている最中に新規に設定した環境変数はexecした新しいシェルにも引き継がれています。